# How to echo customer details after login, in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a customer login which the customer logins with email and application code. When the customer logins correctly it goes to PROFILE.PHP. In that profile I need to fetch and echo the details of the that customer only.

I have tried this what's wrong in this.

PROFILE.PHP

```
<?php
include("session.php");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `loanapp`   WHERE code = '$code' AND email = '$email'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
echo $row['lastname'].'<br>';
echo $row['mobileno'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

SESSION.PHP

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_code'];
$session=mysql_query("SELECT code FROM `loanapp` WHERE code='$check' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($session);
$login_session=$row['code'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

When the customer login correctly, need to echo all the details of that customer.

Comment: "Please Fix This"? Do it yourself.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: can you please show us the form page, and let us know if `session.php` is before or after `profile.php`. Please explain the flow of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

profile.php

```
<?php
session_start()
include("session.php");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `loanapp`   WHERE code = '$code' AND email = '$email'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
  $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
  $_SESSION['mobileno'] = $row['mobileno'];
}
?>
```

Then you can use them whenerver you want
For example,

```
<div><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ByteHamster,
Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Always use the prepare statement.
Here's a quick code for login:

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);

        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = :usr AND userPass = :pas;");
        $stmt->bindParam(':usr', $user);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pas', $pass);

        $stmt->execute();


        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

            echo "User Exists"; // You can retrieve the user data now


        } else {

            echo "non existant";    // wrong username or password       

        }

        $conn = null;  // Disconnect

    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest you to not start the session like `session_start()` in the profile.php as you're already including session.php in the page and have already started session in the session.php.

Also I would suggest to use the function at the start of the page even above including config.php or you can use the session function in config.php as well.

Here is the pretty simple code with explanation.

```
<?php
// Defining variables of values
$email = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];

// Select the data using mysql query
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `loanapp` WHERE code = '$code' AND email = '$email'");

// Looping to get all the data into session
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
  $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
  $_SESSION['mobileno'] = $row['mobileno'];
}
?>
```

What I made changes in the code is:

- Removed `session_start()` in profile.php as per my above suggestion
- used `*` in query in case you need more details from the table in
  future so all you need to add the key with $row. But using * is
  suggested if your table has limited fields
- Used `mysql_fetch_assoc()` for associative array so you can get array
  with key named field name, not any extra numeric keys

> Note: If you're specifying fields in query then you can easily create
>   all the session with field name using foreach loop.

I hope it'll help you to understand conceptual points as well.